# Field with $\operatorname{char}K =p$.

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Let $K$ be a field with $\operatorname{char}K =p$, suppose that $x^p- a$ is irreducíble over $K$ and let $\alpha$ a root of $x^p-a$. Prove that there is no roots of  $x^p - \alpha$ in $K(\alpha)$.

$\textbf{My attempt:}$

It's easy to see that if $\lambda$ is a root of $x^p - \alpha$ then $\lambda$ is the only root of $x^p- \alpha$ (because, $\operatorname{char}K =p$). So, we just need to prove that $\lambda \notin K(\alpha)$, but I can't do that, can you help me??

Comment: An aged mathematician with failing eyesight beseeches you to never use the letters $a$ and $\alpha$ in proximity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $\lambda^p=\alpha$, and write
$$\lambda=\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}k_i\alpha^i,$$
where $k_i\in K$. What happens if you try to expand $\lambda^p$?

Comment: I've tried this way, but, honestly, I didn't see the solution because is hard to expand $\lambda^p$

Comment: @Joãonani Remember that $(x+y)^p=x^p+y^p$ in a field of characteristic $p$.

Comment: Ok, but what can I say about $(x_1+x_2+....+ x_k)^p?$

Comment: See if you can generalize what I said earlier.

Comment: That's it!! $(x_1+ x_2+...+ x_k)^p = x_1^p + x_2^p...+ x_k^p$, thank ya!